# Substring a string based on presence of a character

Tags: java, string

I have a string: `LOAN,NEFT,TRAN`. I want to substring the string based on getting a `,` during traversing the string. So I tried to first get a count for how many `,` are there. but not sure what function to user to get what I want. Also this should be dynamic, meaning I should be able to create as many substrings as required based on number of `,`s. I tried the following code:

```
   package try1;

   public class StringTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="LOAN,NEFT,TRAN";
        int strlen=str.length();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<strlen;i++)
        {
            if(str.contains("'"))
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(""+count);

        for (int j=0;j<count;j++)
        {
            //code to create multiple substrings out of str
        }
    }
   }
```

But I do not think `contains()` is the function I am looking for because value of count here is coming 0. What should I use?

Comment: First of all ... you're looking for the wrong character in `str.contains("'")`. And secondly, you're closing your `if` with a semicolon. Therefore `count++;` will always be executed, no matter if the String contains the search substring.

Comment: Is this homework where you're not allowed to use certain methods?

Comment: @Adam, No not like that....just trying to learn on my own.

Comment: @Tom, Thanks for the correction, but now it is returning `0`

Comment: @Mistu4u Does my answer help, do you need any more information? Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split to get substrings directly:

```
String[] substrings = str.split(",");
```

Is this what you want as an output: (shown below)?

```
["LOAN", "NEFT", "TRAN"] // Array as an output
```

Or to just get the count of the splitting char, you can use the same line as above with this:

```
int count = substrings.length - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't actually count the , characters because 1) contains doesn't take into account your loop variable 2) it's searching for ', not ,

Assuming you want to work at a low level rather than using high level functions like .split(), then I'd recommend the following.

```
for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == ',') {
       count++;
    }
}
```